# Using MemoryStream to write .docx file on remote location c#

Tags: c#, interop, memorystream, word-addins

I am generating MemoryStream from string and pass it to another method which will save that Stream at remote loaction in form of `.docx` file.

```
public static MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(s);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

Above code is for convert the string to MemoryStream. The string I am passing to the above method is XML which I get by `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.WordOpenXML` line.

File successfully get uploaded to remote location but as I download that file, MS Word throws an error that `File is corrupted. Either part of file is missing or invalid` (As shown in below image)

[image]

I am not able to get that whether the Stream I am generating is wrong/corrupted or I need to perform some more operation to make this `.docx` file valid?

Sorry for this question, there are so many questions like this, but none could be more helpful.

Comment: Have you examine the content of the file afterwards? Are you sure it's valid to save that string just as a docx file and expect it to work?

Comment: @JonSkeet I presume it that It would be the way to save the docx file. Correct me If I am wrong, any other way to perform this task?

Comment: "I presume it that It would be the way to save the docx file." I would check that assumption. (Certainly docx files aren't *usually* just plain-text XML files.)

Comment: @JonSkeet So, Do I have to save file temporarily and read that file and pass it to the stream, is that the best way I could manage this issue?

Comment: Read this, it is similar to what you do: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mcsuksoldev/2010/04/09/sending-an-email-from-within-microsoft-word-with-the-word-document-attached/

Comment: @DragosPop tried this, but somehow it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

The XML passed this way is not a valid DOCX file.  The actual DOCX format uses compressed content with folders.  You need to save the document from your add in to a temporary location (best use [GetTempPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath?view=netframework-4.7.2%60), then read the file from disk into your memory stream and upload it wherever you need.

Comment: By this way, It is working completely. But Is there a way to access that content directly and pass it to MemoryStream and save it as a normal word file?

Comment: As far as I know - this is not possible, because, as I said, the content is structured and compressed when saved in DOCX.